# Finding .icns files swift

Tags: swift, icons

This is my code. All the lines execute but only the last line works because thats the last line that has to get executed. Does any one know how I can maybe put all this code into one line or make all of the lines actually execute. Thanks

```
override func controlTextDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {

    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Applications/\(Search.stringValue).app/Contents/Resources/AppIcon.icns")
    Theimageicon.image = NSImage(byReferencingURL: url)

    let url2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Applications/\(Search.stringValue).app/Contents/Resources/icon.icns")
    Theimageicon.image = NSImage(byReferencingURL: url2)

    let url3 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Applications/\(Search.stringValue).app/Contents/Resources/\(Search.stringValue).icns")
    Theimageicon.image = NSImage(byReferencingURL: url3)

}
```

Comment: I have reverted your question edit. It changed the question completely and invalidated the already posted answer. – You should post a new question instead if necessary (and consider to *accept* the answer if it helped).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think all lines execute, but you change the value of theImageIcon.image three times, so you can see at the end  the third one.

Comment: @Nate You're welcome! You can accept my answer if it helped you

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I don't how to fix the problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. You can't group all the lines into one, AFAIK. If you want to keep the three images, your should use Theimageicon1.image = NSImage..., Theimageicon2.image = NSImage... and Theimageicon3.image = NSImage... or Theimageicon.image1 = NSImage..., Theimageicon.image2 = NSImage... and Theimageicon.image3 = NSImage... depending on how you organise the data in your objects